# Else statement is running even though it is false

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, alarm

The original code I tried was this:

```
chrome.alarms.create("check-tabs", { periodInMinutes: .01, when: Date.now() + 500 });

chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener(function (alarm) {
    if (alarm.name == "check-tabs") {
        console.log("check-tabs");
        chrome.tabs.query({ active: false, lastFocusedWindow: false }, function (tabs) {
            for (i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
                if (chrome.alarms.get(tabs[i].url) == undefined) {
                    chrome.alarms.create(tabs[i].url, { when: Date.now() + 10 * 1000 })
                }
            }
        });
    } else {
        console.log("not check-tabs, got alarm");
    }
});
```

But the else statement would just ignore that it was the wrong alarm and display "not check-tabs". The same thing happened when i changed else to:

```
else if (alarm.name != "check-tabs")
```

The result was the same.
The problem gets fixed when I change the code to:

```
chrome.alarms.create("check-tabs", { periodInMinutes: .01, when: Date.now() + 500 });

chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener(function (alarm) {
    if (alarm.name == "check-tabs") {
        console.log("check-tabs");
        chrome.tabs.query({ active: false, lastFocusedWindow: false }, function (tabs) {
            for (i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
                if (chrome.alarms.get(tabs[i].url) == undefined) {
                    chrome.alarms.create(tabs[i].url, { when: Date.now() + 10 * 1000 })
                }
            }
        });
    } else if (alarm.name == "random-alarm-name") {
        console.log("not check-tabs, got alarm");
    }
});
```

But in my code there are going to be multiple alarm names that are created when the code is running, so the names aren't concrete.

Note: I know it is not because of the alarm created by the first if statement, I tested it without creating that alarm and the result was the same.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Did you try changing the anonymous function into an actual function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Likely your listener code gets called multiple times. Add an unconditional `condole.log('called ' + alarm.name)`, and see how many of those get printed.

Comment: It is getting called multiple times because the alarm is repeated every half a second but it is being printed the same amount of times as the other statements printed.

Comment: Never mind you were right, the listener is also being called by alarms that i created before.

Comment: I added `chrome.alarms.clearAll();` and it worked. Thanks!